# How to make 2 entities of the same class interact?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get 2 "people" of the same class to interact with each other, and change each other's "stats." However, I get the error, "formal argument cannot be a constant."

```
class Hands 
  attr_reader :name, :element, :skill, :mana, :health, :attack, :fire, :water, :lyfe

  def initialize(name, element, skill)
    @mana = 100
    @health = 200
    @name = name
    @element = element
    @skill = skill
  end

  def mana 
   sleep 1
    puts "#{@name} has #{@mana} mana."
  end

  def health
    sleep 1
    puts "#{@name} has #{@health} HP."
  end

  def restore(Hands)
    if @element == "Lyfe"
      @mana = 100
      puts "#{@name} has been restored!"
    else 
      puts "#{@name} cannot use this ability!"
    end
  end
end

player1 = Hands.new('Silk', 'Lyfe', 'Summon')
player2 = Hands.new('Nubz', 'Lyfe', 'Manipulate Wildlife')
player3 = Hands.new('Lisk', 'Water', 'Invisible')
player4 = Hands.new('Azzi', 'Water', 'Manipulate Water')
player5 = Hands.new('Zeph', 'Fire', 'Lightning')
player6 = Hands.new('Ford', 'Fire', 'Manipulate Fire')
player7 = Hands.new('Boyd', 'Fire', 'Craft')

player1.restore("Nubz")
```

Here I am trying to get player1 to "restore" player2 back to full mana.
I know the code isn't perfect, but I'm not sure how else to do this.
Focussing on the restore command, the others work fine.

Comment: Try using a lowercase name for your restore argument (e.g. `def restore(hands)`). In Ruby, constants start with an uppercase letter, the error message you're experiencing is saying that you can't have a constant as a parameter to the method being defined.

Comment: That helped, although it isn't doing what I'd like it to do. How I'm getting an output but it is restoring player1, not player2.

Comment: You should be able to modify your method to pass in the player you want to be restored, rather than just the name string, (e.g. `player1.restore(player2`).

Comment: That's what I did, and it still came out to restore player1.

Comment: I posted an answer with a more detailed breakdown of what changes would be needed.

Comment: Aside from what Zoran mentioned (and is the immediate reason for the error), you definition of `restore` does not make sense: You pass it an argument, but you never **use** this argument. While this is not an error from the viewpoint of Ruby, it is most likely an error in the logic of your program.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to pass the instance of the player you want affected to the `restore` method rather than the name string. You can then update that player's attributes as needed. A quick example:

Update class to make `mana` writeable:

```rb
class Hands 
  attr_reader :name, :element, :skill, :mana, :health, :attack, :fire, :water, :lyfe
  attr_writer :mana

  # ...
end
```

Update `restore` method to accept player instance:

```rb
def restore(hands)
  if element == "Lyfe"
    hands.mana = 100
    puts "#{hands.name} has been restored!"
  else 
    puts "#{name} cannot use this ability!"
  end
end
```

Pass instance to method:

```rb
player1 = Hands.new('Silk', 'Lyfe', 'Summon')
player2 = Hands.new('Nubz', 'Lyfe', 'Manipulate Wildlife')

player1.restore(player2)
#=> Nubz has been restored!
```

Comment: I didn't even know the attr_writer existed lol. Thank you so much. Edit; Maybe it's an issue with replit, but it still says that player1 is being restored. Edit 2: I'm just an idiot, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Anytime, glad it helped!